# How to embed a double quote in a C string?

Tags: c, string, char, strtok

My string is in JSON which means it has quotation (`"`) marks all the way through for values and keys.

Trying to use delimiters and sub delimiters, I can't figure out a way to add quotations as part of the delim as well without getting a syntax error. Is there a step I'm missing? Trying to keep the code simple and compact.

Code

```
 char* delim = "{}";
 char* subdelim = ":,";   

char *str1, *token, *name, *value;

int parse_count = 0;
for (str1 = stringToParse; parse_count<num ; str1 = NULL) {
    token = strtok(str1, delim);
    if (token == NULL)
        break;
    name = strtok(token, subdelim);
    value = strtok(NULL, subdelim);
    if (name == NULL || value == NULL) {
        continue;
    }
    strcpy (ptr->name, name);
    strcpy (ptr->value, value);
    ptr++;
    parse_count++;

   }
 return name_values;
}
```

Input String is a char* array: (Sorry, string is a cert)

```
 {"first name":"Jhon","thumbprint":"*********","issuer":"CN=dccw, OU=cswde, O=xswe, 
 L=sdewc","validto":"Mon Jan 01 22:59:59 EST 
 2018","lastname":"Doe","userid":"DJhon","valid from":"Mon Aug 15 
 00:00:00 EDT 2011","subjectInfor":"************"}
```

Output:

```
 printf("%s=%s\n", params->name, params->value);

 "first name"="Jhon"
 "last name"="Doe"
 "userid"="DJhon"
```

Comment: Hi Cup, no, where should it go exactly?

Comment: Note that on a 64-bit machine, there are 8 bytes reserved for the pointer `delim` and an additional 3 for the string it points at, compared with just 3 bytes used for `char delim[] = "{}";` (and it would be good to make that `const char delim[] = "{}";`). Similarly for `subdelim`, of course.  Note that numbers, and `true`, `false` and `null` are not enclosed in strings in [JSON](http://www.json.org/).  You also don't seem to be handling arrays yet.

Comment: Will make sure to add those changes. Also i can't find a way to retrieve the issuer value as a whole string since i have declared "," as part of the string delimiter. Any suggestion on how I can get that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping it should correct your issue...

```
char* subdelim = "\":,";
```

Comment: You were almost there. Just change your work slightly. Your suggestion actually removed the words as well. So I opted to add the delim as part of the first occurrence. Thanks!